# Is State<T> only available for recompose in Android Studio Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have read the article [State and Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state).

I see the UI will be recomposed automatically when a `State<T>` variable is changed in Android Studio Compose.

Does it mean the `State<T>`  is unique variable who can recompose UI automatically ?  and must other types such as `LiveData`, `Flow` be convert to a State in order to update UI automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to convert them as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose).

> Key Point: Compose will automatically recompose from reading State objects.
>
> If you use another observable type such as LiveData in Compose, you should convert it to State before reading it in a composable using a composable extension function like LiveData.observeAsState().

[image: Docs]